# ANDROID - method inside AsyncTask with Buttons to start and cancel

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing some exercises and I need some help.

I have 2 buttons, 1 to start the method and other to cancel. This method calls **Tarea** and it returns a Long(value). I have to make a AsyncTask to run this method and return on a TOAST the Long when it is canceled or ends.

```
public class Actividad1 extends Activity {

    Long valor = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    private AsyncTask tarea = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long>(){

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return valor;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Actividad1.this, "Valor: " + valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Actividad1.this, "Valor: " + valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            super.onCancelled();
        }                                   
    };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad1);
}

public void clickBotonEjecutar (View view){
    Tarea(tarea);
    tarea.execute();

}

public void clickBotonCancelar (View view){
    tarea.cancel(true);      

}


public Long Tarea(AsyncTask tarea) {
    Long valor = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    while (! tarea.isCancelled() && valor <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("Se está ejecutando…" + valor);
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        valor ++;
    }
    return valor;
```

}
}

> The code must be on this format, with a method called **public Long
>   Tarea(AsyncTask tarea)**, and with **private AsyncTask tarea = new
>   AsyncTask()** because is how my teacher want.

Answer (score 0):

you're not being able to click cancel because `doInBackground` is probably executing in a few nanoseconds (REALLY REALLY FAST).

To be able to click `cancel` before the method finishes you should probably put a `Sleep` inside it.

PS.: I'm only suggesting it because it's a simple exercise to show the AsyncTask being executed. I would never suggest to anyone EVER use a sleep in anything at all.